# How can smaller distance between columns?BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code

```
  <div class="container-fluid" >
  <p class="text-center" style="color:white">Hello World!</p>
  <p class="text-center" style="color:white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequa</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="">

<img src="wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/b1.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="">
     <img src="wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/b2.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="">
    <img src="wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/b3.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently my site look like

http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=17

The distance between the image is too big ... I want to be a shorter distance.
I am beginner in using bootrstrap's
How can I reduce the distance?

Can you help me please to solve this problem?

Thanks in avance!

Answer (score 1):

You can nest images directly in the div with class .row, and add to .row div class "text-center". Images must have display: inline-block; in this case.

Comment: can you show me an example please? to understand better

Comment: Yes sure. Can you look at the: http://codepen.io/_danko/pen/yyrxBN ? This link is temporary and will be erased later.

Comment: codepen is now updated with imageholders. can you provide design becouse I do not know where you need to put text?

Comment: Please, check the same link again. It is updated. I am looking forward for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Float the left image right like so

float: right;

and float the right image left like so

float: left;

Comment: I have three columns ... if you do what you say between column 2 and 3 remains greater distance